# How to mix strings the way I am looking for?

Tags: java, string, char

First of all, keep in mind I am new at this, so smart guys, be nice!

I am trying to understand why in this line:

```
for(i = word.length() -1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

I get my string replied to me backwards fine (answer: oaiCgiiB), and in this line of code:

```
for(i = 0 ; i <= word.length(); i++)
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

I get an error...

```
Beijing ChicagoException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 15
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at p200548.main(p200548.java:43)
```

I want the second one to work like the first one but instead of output BiigCiao

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for(i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++) the index is zero-based

Comment: Rather than `i<= word.length(); `use `i < word.length();` in second for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i = 0 ; i <= word.length()-1; i++)  //add mines 1 here
System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

you have to add -1 to `;word.length()-1;`

because word starts at index "**0**" and ends with "**word.length()-1**"

Answer (score 3):

Because you are out of bounds.

While:

```
for(i = word.length() -1; i >= 0; i--)
System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

for length = 3, uses the indexes 2, 1, 0, the following:

```
for(i = 0 ; i <= word.length(); i++)
System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

uses the indexes 0, 1, 2, 3. And 3 is out of bounds for length = 3.

You probably want:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++)
System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
```

which would use the indexes 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

In C language you would not get an exception because it does not care about crossing bounds of an array. This is one of the problems in C. Java, however always checks for bounds and gives you a 'IndexOutOfBoundsException' whenever you try to access an index outside array.

An equivalent code in C:

```
for(i = 0 ; i <= strlen(word); i++)
    printf("%c",word[i]);
```

would work fine as word[length] is '\0' and there is no problem printing it